# How does diffusion model (DDPM) ensures novel generated samples?

Tags: deep-learning, generative-model, diffusion-models

I am trying to understand the theoretical aspect of the denoising diffusion model. There we try to destroy the initial image x_0 through a chain of forward process and then learn a backward diffusion model through a neural network which predicts the noise (to remove) at each step.

I can't understand how does the model ensures that the generated sample after the reversed process, generated a sample from the initial distribution but different from the training samples.

After all, we are using the same trained neural network for the noise removal steps. Then how are we getting a different solution every-time? What is the mathematical support of this preposition?